# Spree - access to Order class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

I have a problem with extending a spree controller. When I override the controller I cannot get access to the Order class. I get the following error (I use **spree 1.2.4**):

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Spree::Admin::OrdersController::Order):
spree_russian_post/app/controllers/admin/orders_controller_decorator.rb:9:in `sample_method'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
...
```

The problem is in my controller:

`spree_russian_post/app/controllers/admi /orders_controller_decorator.rb`

Here is the Code:

```
require 'spree_core'

Spree::Admin::OrdersController.class_eval do

  def sample_method
      @order = Order.find_by_param(params[:id]) #Here I get the error
      ....
  end

end
```

What should I do to get access to the Order class?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that Spree thinks you are looking for the constant `Spree::Admin::OrdersController::Order`

Change your query to **`@order = Spree::Order.find(params[:id])`**

Spree will then know that you are looking for the spree object that is associated with the spree_orders table